# How can we add new fields in a new tab in user setting in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

How can we add new fields in a new tab in user setting in TYPO3 version 8.7?
Our problem is the creation of a new tab.

I can add new fields to personal data tab in user setting, but I need to create new fields into a new tab. 
For backend admin user setting I added a new tab, but for user setting I want to try this. I have an extension and since the installation of the extension it will add-on.

I tried to create new tab in fe_user.php.
Previously I tried to change `ext_tables.php`, but that is not working at all.

```
// Add some fields to FE Users table to show TCA fields definitions 
// USAGE: TCA Reference > $GLOBALS['TCA'] array reference >
// ['columns'][fieldname]['config'] / TYPE: "select" 
$temporaryColumns = array (
    'tx_examples_options' => array (
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'tx_examples_options',
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'select',
            'showitem' => array (
                array('LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:fe_users.tx_examples_options.I.0', '1'),
                array('LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:fe_users.tx_examples_options.I.1', '2'),
                array('LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:fe_users.tx_examples_options.I.2', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:fe_users.tx_examples_options.I.3', '3'),
            ),
            'size' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 1,
        )
    ),
    'tx_examples_special' => array (
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'tx_examples_special',
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'user',
            'size' => '30',
            'userFunc' => 'Documentation\\Examples\\Userfuncs\\Tca->specialField',
            'parameters' => array(
                'color' => 'blue'
            )
        )
    ), 
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'fe_users',
    $temporaryColumns 
); 
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'fe_users',
    '--div--;newtab,tx_examples_options, tx_examples_special' 
);
```

When I changed into file ext_tables.php

```
 $GLOBALS['TYPO3_USER_SETTINGS']['columns']['copy_directory'] = array(
       'label' => 'Alternative directory for saving copies',
       'type' => 'text',
       'table' => 'be_users',
    );
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToUserSettings('copy_directory','after:lang');
```

then it's showing in "personal data" tab but I want new tab in user setting for non-admin user.

Comment: I follow the link 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html
but not working

Comment: Thanks @Bernd Wilke πφ, for correct my question, 
Can you please answer my question, Is it possible?

Comment: I will try, so I'm not very familiar with that topic.

Answer (score 0):

In general your code looks fine.
But you are in the wrong file!
Avoid `ext_tables.php` if possible.

If you change anything to the TCA you should do it in `Configuration/TCA/` for new tables and `Configuration/TCA/Overrides` for enhancing existing tables.
Use filenames according to the table you are modifying.

**In your case all the code should be located in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php`.**

And be sure you clear all caches if you develop anything with TCA!

Comment: Hello @brend, thanks for reply,
Yes I tried with Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php this file to show tab and fields in user setting, but no fields added, thats why I added to file ext_tables.php so atleast it showing in existing tab in user setting but I need new tab their. 
Also I want to know that fe_user changes will be for backend admin created non admin user or front end signup/login user? or both type of user ?

Comment: I am having the same problem when adding a parameter to the backend users. I tried Overrides/be_users.php but it didn't work so had to add it to ext_tables.php instead